# Wave form distortion in AD9833

Tags: signal, filter, dds

When using AD9850, I can see a very clean and smooth sine wave  but this is not the case by AD9833. In AD9833 multiple steps are visible in the output that gets worse in higher frequencies( > 2MHz) .The output looks as if the DAC never goes under smoothing process. I want to know if this is an inherent nature of this device or I am missing something? Should I use a low pass filter to remove these steps? The output looks like this in 2MHz:[image]

Comment: Is the actual frequency displayed on your scope 2.273MHz? If so then these are definitely samples.

Comment: This happens in all frequencies but more visible in higher frequencies. I tried many frequencies between 400Hz to 5MHz.

Comment: @Andyaka Would you please explain a little more about "samples"? I couldn't understand that

Comment: Your waveform looks like it has 23 clocks in two cycles. As clock is running at 25MHz, this divided by \$\frac{23}{2}\$ = 2.273MHz

Comment: @Andyaka Clever!. This photo is on 2MHz which is a good approximation made by you. So this means this is an inherent problem of the device and the only solution is a low pass filter?

Comment: It's not inherent just to the device but to the entire approach. A higher sampling rate will make the steps less visible but a proper solution will involve a steep low pass filter below Fs/2 (probably 5 to 10 MHz in your case). Search terms : anti-aliasing filter, DAC reconstruction filter.

Comment: Yeah it just takes a decent low pass filter like Brian says. But there's a little more if amplitude flatness is to be maintained because as a reconstructed sinewave approaches nyquist it's fundamental amplitude noticeably drops so you need a little peak in the low pass response, prob about 2dB at 7MHz but there are formula. Filter trial and error might be a decent approach in tweaking it.

Comment: @Andyaka Low pass filter is a good idea. Although an improvement appeares in the sine wave form but a bigger problem would arise:  Triangular waves will change to sinusoidal waves and squares will be ramp shaped.

Comment: @Aug certainly they would but that is the problem with DDS at higher frequencies. As a sine generator the imperfections can be largely eradicated by a filter. Square waves won't look good anyway because the rise time (one sample width) will look slow.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Your discussion and Brian's led me to this conclusion that I should move from AD9833 to AD9850 for its higher frequency and steps and using its inbuilt comparator to make a square wave and then using an integrator to make triangular wave. I tried this new theory and it works fine now. As your guidance led me to this result please put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your waveform looks like it has 23 clocks in two cycles. As clock is running at 25MHz, this divided by \$\frac{23}{2}\$ = 2.273MHz.

This is the problem in a nutshell. If you are happy with that DDS device you need to apply a steep order low pass filter incorporating a sinc-compensation filter. At 25MHz sampling the highest frequency "quality" sinewave you are going to get will be about 8MHz and this would require something like an 8th order low pass filter to smooth over the cracks.

The sinc compensation filter is because the fundamental content of a digitized waveform gets smaller as you approach nyquist frequency; the harmonics get bigger and RMS stays the same but the fundamental sinewave amplitude gets smaller. [Here](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3853.pdf) is a good article by Maxim entitled "flatten DAC frequency response app note 3853".

Of course the bigger problem is when you need a square wave or triangle wave and perhaps the only solution is go for a faster device like the one you mentioned, the AD9850.

Comment: Sinc compensation is necessary - not because of sampling per se - but because the waveform is reconstructed as square steps - and the frequency response from a square impulse is a sinc function. If you reconstructed the waveform using infinitely short pulses its freq response would be flat; narrower pulses or raised cosines would reduce or remove the need for sinc compensation (but the square/sinc approach is probably easier!)

Comment: @BrianDrummond - very true but it's difficult to find a DAC that does it any other way!!

Comment: generally yes, but in audio applications, this was one of the main reasons to adopt oversampling DACs; it moved the sinc filter issue out of the audio band...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is normal for a DDS if the output frquency comes close to the input clock frquency. It can be removed by filtering.

Comment: But I am using 25MHz clock.

Comment: I think this device should work fine up to 12.5 MHz with a 25MHz Clock. What is the best cutoff frequency for that low pass filter? 30 MHz or so?

Comment: In this context 2 MHz is "close" to 25 MHz, I mean it is not "much" (by a factor of some powers of ten) lower than the clock frequency.

Comment: The cutoff frequency of the LP filter should be _lower_ than the clock frequency (i.e. < 25 MHz, but of course higer than your output frequency).

Comment: BTW: the device _is_ working (theoretically up to 1/2 clock). The stair pattern is not a bug, it's a feature :-)

Comment: No, basic sampling theory (Shannon, Nyquist) tell us the cutoff frequency should be lower than HALF the clock frequency.

Comment: @Brian Drummond: yes, agree